# W3C Validator doesn't like the use of <form> for xhtml 1.1 strict?

Tags: html, xhtml-1.1

I get thrown out a bunch of errors on the xhtml 1.1 validator (W3C) whenever I use a  element.

As soon as I change the element to a `<div>` all the errors disappear.

In browsers the forms work in both states (as a `<div>` or as a `<form>` element, minus the fact that when I use `<div>`, the submit button will not work.

Anyone have any ideas as to why the it's coming up as invalid?

```
<form class="form"> 
        Name:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="firstname"/><br/>
        Email Address:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
        Comments:<br/>
        <textarea name="Comments" rows="10" cols="50">Please enter your comments here.</textarea><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Done"/><br/>
    </form>
```

[LINK: Screenshot of a few of the validator errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJwm1.png)

Comment: I think you need an `action` attribute in your form

Comment: This has nothing to do with XHTML 1.1. All HTML versions have the same requirement, and the validator emits the error for all of them.

Comment: On the plus side, kudos for learning XHTML 1.1, which is the most sensible of all XHTML dialects.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the question, because the validator is telling you exactly what's wrong.

You need an `action` attribute on your form.

Don't use `<br>` to format your markup.

Surround your input labels in actual `<label>` elements, and have them associated with their appropriate inputs via the `for` attribute matching the input's `id`.  In XHTML you can't have text in the document that isn't appropriately wrapped in an element.

```
<form action="#insert_your_action_here">
  <label for="first_name" class="block-label">
    Name:
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="first_name" name="firstname">
</form>
```

Use CSS to format your labels and inputs:

```
.block-label { 
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I literally have only been doing HTML properly for under a week, it just through me is all xD

Comment: np and good luck.  A good resource you may want to check out, for learning HTML, would be MDN (google mdn html).